# What is the difference between CreateAsync and IndexAsync methods on ElasticSearch NEST client?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I found that `Create()` method needs an `Id` field in the entity class but `Index()` doesn't need it. I cannot figure out why.

Comment: cant figure out. im getting lost in the documentation

Comment: post a link to the doco here for the relevant API calls

Comment: with due respect, if i could find that i know how to read it

Comment: i see - so give me a link to the root of the doco and i'll see if i can find it for you

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/index.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a fundamental difference between the create and index APIs in Elasticsearch;

1. [create API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#operation-type) will create the document if it does not exist, and will return an error if it does exist. The create API request **must** contain the index, type and id in the request URI. The [id field *can* be inferred from the POCO](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/ids-inference.html) *or* can be explicitly set on the request.
2. [index API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html) will create the document if it does not exist and will overwrite the document if it does exist. Passing an id is optional, and if an id is not passed, Elasticsearch will generate an id for the document.

This difference is reflected in the `Create()` and `Index()` methods exposed on the .NET clients.