# ElasticSearch .NET DeleteByQueryAsync on Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch 8.9.1

Tags: .net, elasticsearch

I am updating my .NET project from NEST 6.8.8 to Elastic.Clients.Elasticsearch 8.9.1

I have method that should just delete documents from index that are older than given date. On the NEST version it works but not on the Elastic.Clients.ElasticSearch

On the NEST version this code did work

```
        var result = await _client.DeleteByQueryAsync<object>( d => d
            .Index(index)
            .Query(q => q.DateRange(r => r
                .Field(field)
                .LessThanOrEquals(date)
            )));
```

But in the Elastic.Client.ElasticSearch this gives "The delegate type could not be inferred" error.

I have method that uses SearchAsync method and similar syntax works with that.

I have tried to find examples how to use DeleteByQuery with Elastic.Clients.ElasticSearch but haven't found any.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My colleague found correct format for this

```
        DeleteByQueryResponse result = await _client.DeleteByQueryAsync<object>(index,
            d => d
                .Query(q => q
                    .Range(r => r
                        .DateRange(dr => dr
                            .Field(field)
                            .Lt(date)))));
```

Comment: Do you also managed the UpdateByQueryAsync? Because the client asks for the internal elastic search ID, but I don't have it when I update my document. Thank you

Comment: I think I will use CreateAsync(), instead of IndexAsync() when I create a new document. In this way I can use my unique internal ID, as Elasticsearch document ID. Here is explained the difference between Index and Create in the client library (for NEST v. 7, but the methods are present also in v. 8.x): https://stackoverflow.com/a/53040074